# Is Daniel Tammet a savant?

Tags: psychology, memory

I was reading about the so called 'savant' [Daniel Tammet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Tammet) after I saw the TV show *Brain Man*.

After I read the book ["Moonwalking with Einstein"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0143120530) by [Joshua Foer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Foer) I read that Daniel Tammet's real name was Daniel Paul Corney and he had being working hard for many hours by hard memory training to build up his skills, ie he was NOT born with the skills as he claims.

The more I investigate it, it become more clear to me that all his claims about autism and 'savant' in the TV show 'Brain Man' is inaccurate.

Is it true?

Comment: There a good long discussion about Tammet at a [mnemonics forum](http://mt.artofmemory.com/forums/daniel-tammet-840.html).

Comment: Your summary of his pi memorisation seems awfully biased and unfair. You make it sound like he was lying and he "only" memorised 2965 digits, where your link makes it clearer that it was initially thought that he HAD achieved the record, but it turned out he made one mistake in the first 22,514 places, so he title was revoked.

Comment: Actually, the more I read this, the more I think this question is a reflection on your idea of what a 'savant' is. It appears you don't think savants need to study. I'm going to close this while we work out what you mean.